# Is there a difference between text/plain and string?

Tags: javascript, java, axios, put

I am trying to send a Put request to an older Java back end. The path on the back end is

```
@PUT
@Path("/foo/bar")
@Consumes("text/plain")
public String someFunction(String ExpectedArgument){
//Unrelated logic
}
```

I'm trying to send a string from the front end using Javascript and Axios.

```
let someString = 'Example String'
axios.put('/foo/bar',someString).then(resp=>console.log(resp))
```

Unfortunately, when I try to do this, I'm receiving an HTTP 415 error for bad content type. Reviewing other, successful put requests that I've made, the only difference I've found is that this one has the "@Consumes("text/plain")" line in it. I can only conclude that there's some difference between what the java is expecting as text/plain and what I'm providing with a javascript string.

I would like to know what about my string is causing it to be rejected and how I can edit my code so that the back end will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
const headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
}
let someString = 'Example String'
axios.put('/foo/bar', someString, {
    headers: headers
  }).then(resp=>console.log(resp))
```

Comment: That's the darndest thing. I tried that earlier and it didn't work, but as soon as I used your code, it did. I must have made a typo.

I'm assuming that there's something in the Java that has to check the headers to determine whether or not they're correct, and that the default value from an axios call is not the "text/plain" that it's looking for. Thank you.

Comment: @NegativeFriction If you say that the payload must have a certain MIME type, then it has to have a header that says it is that MIME type.